# Query and give a count per group

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am looking for help with creating a QUERY to give a total number of times a class is listed. Thank you so much for any help. My head hurts from banging it against a wall trying to solve this.

Spreadsheet has a column for:

- Clan Name ( 1 of the 3 clan names are in the column cell per row. clanA, clanB, clanC)
- Class (1 class per cell per row. choice of classA, classB, classC, classD, classE, classF)

Trying to craft a query that will give a result like this:

| Clan Name | Class | Total per Class |
| --- | --- | --- |
| clanA | classA | # |
|  | classB | # |
| clanB | classA | # |

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with realistic-looking data.

Comment: include your source data.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `group by` clause, like this:

`=query(Data!A1:B, "select A, B, count(B) where B is not null group by A, B", 1)`

The formula will repeat the clan name on every row. To only show the first instance, use a [conditional formatting](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413) custom formula rule in result column `A2:A`, like this:

`=A1`

The format in the rule should set the text color to white.